# Why does Neh. 8:17 say that nobody celebrated the Festival of Tabernacles since Joshua, when Solomon celebrated it in 1 Kgs. 8:65?

Tags: contradiction, 1-kings, solomon, nehemiah

When Nehemiah celebrates the Festival of Tabernacles for the first time with the returning exile from Babylon, it is stated that

> From the days of Joshua son of Nun until that day, the Israelites had not celebrated it like this. (Neh. 8:17 NIV)

However, how can this be true if, as said in 1 Kgs. 8:65 (NIV), after Joshua, Solomon also celebrated it?

> So Solomon observed the festival at that time, and all Israel with him—a vast assembly, people from Lebo Hamath to the Wadi of Egypt. They celebrated it before the Lord our God for seven days and seven days more, fourteen days in all.

How can this be reconciled? Does Nehemiah refer instead to the character of the festivities instead of the celebration of the festival itself? If so, how?

Comment: [Commentaries](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/nehemiah/8-17.htm) seem to say that either there was not such a joyous celebration since Joshua, or that not *all* the people had live in tents since Joshua.